# Calculate amount of time until the next hour

Tags: javascript, time

I'm working on a busing website project and the buses run every hour. I'm having trouble creating a widget that finds the time between now and the next hour, so that it is clear when the next bus will run. My client requires that it is in javascript. Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: You don't really need the time until the next hour, you need the time plus a delta, unless there's only *one* stop on the bus route and the bus arrives there exactly on the hour.

Answer (score 14):

To know exactly the miliseconds from now to the next hour:

```
function msToNextHour() {
    return 3600000 - new Date().getTime() % 3600000;
}
```

Please note that this will strictly tell you how many milliseconds until the NEXT hour (if you run this at 4:00:00.000 it will give you exactly one hour).

Answer (score 6):

```
function getMinutesUntilNextHour() { return 60 - new Date().getMinutes(); }
```

Note that people who's system clocks are off will miss their bus. It might be better to use the server time instead of the time on the client's computer (AKA at least partly a non-client-side-javascript solution).

Answer (score 1):

you have the Date object in Javascript, you could do something like:

```
var now = new Date();
var mins = now.getMinutes();
var secs = now.getSeconds();
var response = "it will be " + (60 - mins - 1) + " minutes and " + (60 - secs) + " seconds until the next bus";
```

of course you will have to work more on those calculations, but that's how you work with time in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Either of the other two answers will work well, but are you aware of the docs available to you about all the other nice things date is JS can do for you?

[Mozilla Date Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers, a really simple function to get the rounded minutes remaining to the next hour is:

```
function minsToHour() {
  return 60 - Math.round(new Date() % 3.6e6 / 6e4);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to subtract `Date#getMinutes()` from 60 rather than the approach here? It's hard to tell what's going on, I'm pretty sure it's off by one minute, and it fails for dates far in the past. Plus, the `getMinutes` approach is less code to write and easier to remember.

Comment: Why would people be waiting for buses "far in the past"? Anyhow,it's just another way of doing it. The above rounds so within the last 30 seconds it should show 0, using *getMintues()* will show 0 within the last minute unless you also deal with seconds. But I doubt it matters anyway, how precisely do the busses stick to the schedule?