# Looping javascript timer that ignores Web page refresh

Tags: javascript, html

No experience in this matter, obviously - I basically cobbled together code up to this point.

I have demo Website for potential clients to visit - they can log into the dashboard and basically mess everything up and an hour later a cron job will restore a database dump stored elsewhere on the server.

I came across this block of code thinking it would be useful and considerate to show a 60-0 timer, letting visitors know how long before the Website would 'reset.' It then starts at 60. However upon a browser refresh, so does the counter. I styled it with CSS so it had an informative label and the whole block of code went into an HTML widget from the site's dashboard.

I'm thinking this might not be sophisticated enough to handle a browser refresh. Any suggestions?

```
<style type="text/css">
#notice {font-size:150%; float:left; padding-right:10px;}
#time {font-size:150%;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

   var m=60; /*this value may be edited to suit your requirements*/

   var s=0;
   var temp=m-1;

window.onload=function() {
   tenMinutes();
 }
function tenMinutes(){
   s--;
if(s<0) {
   s=59;
   m--;
 }
if(m==-1) {
   m=temp;
 }
if(m<10) {
   mins='0'+m;
 }
else {
   mins=m;
 }
if(s<10) {
   secs='0'+s;
 }
else {
   secs=s;
 }
   document.getElementById('time').firstChild.nodeValue=mins+':'+secs;
   cd=setTimeout('tenMinutes()',1000);
}
</script>
<div style="width:300px;">
<div id="notice">This Website will reset in:</div>
<div id="time">60:00</div></div>
```

Comment: Store the initial time in a cookie and then use this value to compare against when the page is reloaded.

Comment: Guys! Thanks for stepping up to help me but please re-read the first line - I have no experience with this. Most of your suggestions seem to assume I know how to implement any of this. And while I'm not asking for a babysitter, I really need someone to plop down a block of good code or just set me right - "hey dude, this can't be done within the constraints of your environment."And I'll be cool with that.

Comment: Dave, Thanks for the question, but this isn't a site where we do the work for you.

Comment: @ Lee - fair enough. And as I mentioned that's all I need to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you (apparently) control the the cron job, and say it executes every full hour, you can use JavaScript to calculate the [time difference between now and the next hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337616/calculate-amount-of-time-until-the-next-hour).

This, of course, relies on the server and visitor having their clocks in sync, as far as minutes/seconds are concerned. Keep in mind that there are time zones with half-hour offsets and the likes.

If you want it to be more exact, you'll need to have some server-side logic to store the time/date of the next reset.

You can either do it somewhere in your application code, or you could just use the cronjob to write the the time information in a suitable format into your files.

Comment: @MkeSpaGuy The homepage sure looks nice, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

So remember that when the user tells the browser to reload the webpage, its essentially the same thing as you rebooting your computer.  The browser is going to reload the entire page from scratch and that also means that its going to start executing any javascript from the beginning.  There isn't really any way to avoid this.

If you want to avoid that, you have to find a way to avoid having the browser reload the javascript, or probably better, use a persistent data store in order to store data that can tell the browser where it left off before the page was reloaded (like saving a file to disk before rebooting, to continue the metaphor from above).

One idea would be to persist a datetime value to a cookie or back to the server when the page first loads.  You could then check for this value and if it exists assume the timer is started and measure how much time has passed has passed.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since your server time will be in sync with the cron, I would add the time inside your javascript using php [time()](https://www.php.net/time)

As it's been said, obviously hard coding the minutes reset the timer on page reload, and relying on the user's system time is not reliable as it might not be in sync with the server.